# "Hash checksum" object supporting the buffer API required

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to compute hash value of "Disk image" USbImg.E01 in pycharm

```
import hashlib

try:
    file = open("F:/USB Try MATCH/USBTRY.E01",'r')
except:
    print("\nFile not found")
ad5 = hashlib.md5()
ad5.update(file)
print("md5: %s" % ad5.hexdigest())
```

> object supporting the buffer API required

Comment: Try `ad5.update(file.read())`

Answer (score 0):

```
import hashlib
fiename = 'F:/NEWIMG2/ABC.E01'
hashermd5 = hashlib.md5()
with open(fiename,'rb') as open_file:
    content = open_file.read()
    hashermd5.update(content)
print("md5: %s" % hashermd5.hexdigest())
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer